# PHP SimpleXML is wrapping empty nodes around other nodes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have encountered a strange bug in working with simpleXML in php and can't figure out what could be causing it. 
Basically I have a XML template file which I am loading with simpleXML like so:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('template.xml');
```

I then manipulate the node contents and when I save the xml it has wrapped all the empty nodes around other nodes...
So for example the template xml looks like this in part:

```
<Shift shiftPeriod="">
            <Name></Name>
            <Hours></Hours>
            <StartTime></StartTime>
            <EndTime></EndTime>
            <PayTypeHours></PayTypeHours>
            <Comments></Comments>
</Shift>
```

Then When I output the xml using $xml->asXML() that section looks like:

```
<shift shiftperiod="">
<name>
<hours>
<starttime>
<endtime>
<paytypehours>
<comments>
</comments></paytypehours></endtime></starttime></hours></name></shift>
```

So basically it's wrapped those nodes around each other. It's probably something obvious I'm missing but I can't find any other solutions online. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us the code where you are manipulating the contents? The error is clearly happening somewhere in there, as [just loading and re-serializing that XML works fine](http://codepad.viper-7.com/SIOo8W).

Comment: I also notice that the output you show is all lower-case, but your input is mixed case; an XML parser won't do this on your own, so I suspect the output is actually XML you have manually created, and not the input at all.

Comment: OK it's quite a big file. But for example I manipulate the contents using: 
$xml->Shift->Name = "Foo";

Comment: Hmmm yes I suppose that would account for it... but a lot of those fields I'm not even manipulating and they're still in the output, so it must be loading them from the template, but then converting them to lowercase...

Comment: If I add to your fiddle the code I am using and then run it, it does keep the right structure as well. So maybe the xml file it's loading is bad somehow? It validates, but maybe something is missing there?

Comment: It's really hard to speculate without seeing the code. Try starting with as simple a piece of code as you can - load your actual template file, and then immediately run `->asXML()` for instance. Then build up slowly, testing as you go, rather than just knowing that it's "somewhere in this big file of PHP". Not only will creating a simplified example help others reproduce your problem, it may lead you to spot the solution yourself.

Comment: Yeah I ran the exact code I had on codepad and it works fine... so now I'm really confused...http://codepad.viper-7.com/gYRa58. Basically the only difference is that I just dump a form $_post as json and then reencoded it as an array for the test. And output is completely valid.

Comment: Ok so it seems I'm an idiot, which other people could have probably told me anyhow, but apparently just outputting the xml between two "<pre>" tags or echoing it to see what it looks like doesn't seem to format it correctly. If I save the output to an actual file then it's fine. :-) Thanks anyways IMSoP.